# When I was building a maven unit test, I got the following error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, log4j, logback

When I was building a maven unit test, I got the following error.But I don't have this appender caller CONSOLE in the project.And all my logback appender are above on the logger.

```
11:07:59,525 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
11:07:59,526 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [CONSOLE]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
11:07:59,526 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
11:07:59,526 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:07:59,527 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2668c286 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Please see my new comment, it’s my logback file.
Build timed out (after 50 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.

Comment: Paste your logback configuration file here. There's something you are missing in that file.

Comment: Can you show your logging configuration?

Comment: Please see my new comment.

Comment: That's not a comment, it's an answer, and should only be used to answer the question.  If you want to add information to your question, you should [edit] your question and add that information.

Answer (score 0):

`Could not find an appender named [CONSOLE]`

Check logback configuration, but something tells me, that instead of

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
```

you used

```
 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
```

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender

But it's hard to say, as you don't provide your logback configuration.

Cheers

Comment: Please see my new comment, it’s my logback file.

Comment: I have to sleep,please see my config file.

Comment: where is it? I can't see it